# UDP fragmentation in Python standard library

Tags: python, network-programming, udp

Am I right that UDP fragmentation should not be handled by developer himself in Python?

Am I right that I'll get my UDP packet with all originally sent data and not just one fragment of it?

```
while True:
  data, addr = s.recvfrom(65535)
  # Process packet
```

Comment: with udp - you either get the whole packet, or you get nothing. If the packet gets fragmented and you receive 1 fragment but not the other it gets dropped. Unless i'm not understanding your problem. I also recommend you do not try to send packets of that size. MTU is normally around 1500 or so.

Answer (score 0):

You will get the whole datagram that was sent through another UDP socket in one send or write operation. UDP is not stream oriented like TCP.

Comment: So there's no need to worry about fragmentation and I can expect that the whole data will be received in any case, even if this data was divided to the several packets?